# How to Load the KMZ file?

Tags: android, google-maps, kmz

"I have to load a kmz file in to the android application that i am developing and that kmz file will be loaded from sdcard in to the application. So what i should do for that whether there is direct uri intent or i have to parse it by xml parsing if so then how to load coordinates in to the map to show that kmz file.

Comment: Did you find the way to open KMZ files?? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the native v3 KmlLayer, which supports kmz files, subject to the [documented size and complexity restrictions](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport), the kmz file must be publicly available on the web (so google's servers can get to it).

To use a local file (which it sounds like you do), your only option is to use a third party parser like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/).

Answer (score 0):

to open in android studio use below code :

```
    try {
     KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap,R.raw.filename, 
                      getApplicationContext()); 
       // creating the kml layer, put the file in res/raw
     layer.addLayerToMap();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```